# MATLAB bus from struct

Tags: matlab, struct, bus, s-function

I want to hand data from a struct in my MATLAB workspace to an S-function.
To do this I created a bus. The code is compiled without any errors.

When I start the Simulation I get the following error message:

> Invalid
>   structure-format variable specified as workspace input in
>   'untitled/From Workspace'. If the input signal is a bus signal, the
>   variable must be a structure of MATLAB timeseries objects. Otherwise,
>   the variable must include 'time' and 'signals' field, and the
>   'signals' field must be a structure with a 'values' fields.

In my opinion a timeseries object does not make sense, since the values are all constant.

Is there another way to import a MATLAB struct in my S-function?

FYI: I am using the S-Function Builder, since I do not have any experience in C.